# How to avoid creating unused String instances when logging in Java

Tags: java, performance, logging, log4j

I define a Util class to log using log4j, and a method is like below:

```
public static void info(String msg) {
    if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
        logger.info(msg);
}
```

But if the log level is set to "Error" (and thus `logger.isInfoEnabled()` is `false`), and I use the below to log, will the two `String` instances be created?

```
LogUtil.info("String instance" + stringParam);
```

even though these two String instances may be collected by gc, construct a instance will be still costs.

I guess if I check the log level before calling logger.info(msg) may help , but this may the code not clean, that's the reason why I define Util class.

How can I to write a clean code that if I do not set the level to info, it will neither log anything nor create the String instance?

Answer (score 4):

Don't define the Util class and you can avoid some of the string creation overhead.

Quite apart from anything else you're `isInfoEnabled` check is completely pointless as logger itself will do the check.

Use:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Message {0} with {1}", new Object[] { param1, param2 });
```

And you will avoid most of the string creation overhead as it will only `toString()` `param1` and `param2` and construct the final message if the INFO level is turned on.

There is the cost of allocating the new `Object[]` array but that is tiny

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean that in my case I just need my method of info like this"logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0}", new Object[] { msg});"?

Comment: @TimB I suspect that you are using `java.util.logging.Logger` and not the one from Log4J. That logging line you are showing does not work with Log4J.

Comment: @maba you are right, this is not working  for my existing code which is using log4j

Comment: @Jaskey it works with Log4j 2: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html

Comment: @maba ahh, true, good point. I'm surprised log4j doesn't have an equivalent though. (I don't use it myself, it seems pretty pointless when java.util.logging does pretty much everything log4j does and is available in core.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid your util class is completely useless, as the logger already does the log level check internally. The idea of doing these checks manually outside is to reduce the overhead caused by unnecessary code that prepares the log message (mostly `String` concatenation) even if then it is not logged due to the current log level:

Suppose you want to log the user input - which is a `Date` object. Here, date-to-string conversion and string concatenation is done even if the log level is lower than *info*:

```
logger.info("user input: " + dateFormatter.format(userInput));
```

So the solution is to check the log level first:

```
if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
    logger.info("user input: " + dateFormatter.format(userInput));
}
```

*But if you now move the check into a utililty method that gets the full message as parameter, you'll end up having the same problem than above!*

---

Others already explained in their answers how to use the extended log methods to let the logger internally do the formatting:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Current user input: {0}", userInput);
```

But also here, if the parameter has to be specially formatted first, it does not solve the overhead problem. Again, you'll have to do an additional log-level check first.

---

Since **Java 8**, you could write a utility-method that can be used effeciently and smartly by using lambda expressions:

```
public static void info(Supplier<String> messageSupplier) {
    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) logger.info(messageSupplier.get());
}
```

Usage:

```
LoggerUtil.info(() -> "user input: " + dateFormatter.format(userInput));
```

Here, the lambda expression will only be executed if info logging is enabled!

Comment: I know if I check before I logger.info will help, but this may the code not clean since every time I log, I have to write a code of checking....BTW,I have updated the questions..

Comment: @Jaskey I tried to explain why you must do the check every time and can't move it into a utility method (except the Java 8 solution).

Comment: Nowadays the messageSupplier lambda is the way to go.

Comment: @weberjn There is not the one and only "way to go". Lambdas offer the most flexible solution, but for simple message formatting purposes, parameterized messages are still the better and more readable option imho.

Comment: ()->fibRec(1k) is better than "{}",fibRec(1k)   ;-)

Comment: @weberjn yes, but `logger.info(() -> "User " + user.name + " pressed button " + button.name + " " + time + " seconds ago")` is worse than `logger.info("User {} pressed button {} {} seconds ago", user.name, button.name, time)`. Imho highly opinion, but even more situation based. I'd simply decide on a case by case basis. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could also profit from Slf4J logger (defacto new standard in the industry), that has friendlier syntax:

```
logger.info("Configuration directory: {}, {}", param1, param2);
```

It is also possible to configure Slf4J with different back-ends including Log4J. Hope this helps

Comment: would you please share that I do I use SLF4J in the comments? Is it easy to replace my existing code into SLF4J?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty easy! You can migrate from Log4J to Slf4J in few minutes by using automatic [migrator](http://www.slf4j.org/migrator.html)

Comment: And in this case, the param1 and param2 will not be created if the logger level is debug?

Comment: @Jaskey: well, param1 and param2 are just references to some objects, logger does not manage their lifecycle in any way. What will not be created is new String for logger message.

Answer (score 1):

**even though this String instance will be collected by gc,** -

In `logger.info("String instance");` , `"String instance"`  is a *String Literal* and will be created on the String Pool. Unfortunately, it will persist as long as the program runs (i.e, until the JVM shuts down). Use a `StringBuilder` or `String(char[])` to prevent adding the String to the String Pool.

Comment: So does it mean this question is meaningful? Also, what if this is a param which I construct somewhere and pass to the Util?

Comment: @Jaskey - yes. Of course your question makes sense. You shouldn't use - `"strings like this everywhere"`

Comment: so, is it better to use `if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) { logger.info("String literal"); }` to avoid creation of unnecessary string instance if log level is error ?

Comment: @Donatello - Not really. The string literals enclosed within double quotes are created when the class loads. So adding an "if" condition won't prevent the creation